# Green kernel of Hunt processes

Tags: reference-request, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $X$ be a regular Hunt process on $R^+$ with starting at $x$ and $T_y :=\inf\{t>0: X_t=y\}, y\in R^+$. $G_q(\cdot,\cdot), q >0$ denotes Green kernel of the process $X$. 
We have the following result:

$$E_x (e^{-qT_y})=\frac{G_q(x,y)}{G_q(y,y)}.$$

If you know which paper or book mentions about it, please tell me the references.

Thank you very much!